# How do I correctly use ldap_search() in PHP?

Tags: php, ldap

I've spent the better part of the day so far looking into this problem. For some reason, I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going wrong with the code below. It's a trimmed/modified version of the example given at the PHP Manual.

When I run the following code, I receive the error message:

```
Warning: ldap_search() [function.ldap-search]: Search: Operations error in C:\wamp\www\ldap.php on line 12
```

Relevant code:

```
<?php
$ds=ldap_connect("serverName.first.second.third.fourth");

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    $r=ldap_bind($ds);    
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "OU=InfoSystems,OU=Domain Users,DC=first,DC=second,DC=third,ED=fourth", "sn=MyActualSurName");  
    ldap_close($ds);
?>
```

I used a VBS script to print the current logged in user's (Me) full DN. From that, I plugged in the appropriate OU and DC fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more clarification is needed, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#45388

Comment: I have. That was the first thing I stumbled across as a solution. I am using that and LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION to force Version 3, which was another solution that most agree upon as being useful. I have tried using one and not the other as well, with no change in the output.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I spent the last few days working on it some more and nothing has turned up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Our AD server allows for anonymous bind, but apparently does not allow for searching without credentials. The above code works fine once I call ldap_bind() with credentials.